# 2 expandable list views aligned horizontally width: match_parent

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview

I want to create 2 expandable ListViews on the same line in a `linear layout with horizontal orientation`, **to have** the following effect (depending on which list is expanded)

**expected behavior :**

```
**********************************************
* v list1                          | v list2 *
**********************************************
* Item1 List1 or List2                       *
* Item2 List1 or List2                       *
* Item3 List1 or List2                       *
* Item4 List1 or List2                       *
* Item5 List1 or List2                       *
* Item6 List1 or List2                       *
**********************************************
```

The items can be items of `list1` or `list2` when clicking on the prompt. So the need is to have them `match parent` in the width.

this is what I have now (when clicking on list1 I have the first part expanded which has only 3/4 of the parent width, and when clicking on the list2 I only have the second part :

**Current behavior: when click on list1**

```
*************************************************
* v list1                      | v list2        *
*************************************************
* Item1 List1                  *                *
* Item2 List1                  *                *
* Item3 List1                  *                *
* Item4 List1                  *                *
* Item5 List1                  *                *
* Item6 List1                  *                *
*************************************************
```

**Current behavior: when click on list2**

```
*************************************************
* v list1                      | v list2        *
*************************************************
*                              * Item1 List2    *
*                              * Item2 List2    *
*                              * Item3 List2    *
*                              * Item4 List2    *
*                              * Item5 List2    *
*                              * Item6 List2    *
*************************************************
```

so the list items don't have the parent width.

I have done something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adm_ll_media"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ExpandableListView 
            android:id="@+id/adm_list_media"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

        <ExpandableListView 
            android:id="@+id/adm_add_media"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But logically one of them takes 3/4 of the linear layout width and the other 1/4. So what I want to do is to have only the prompts take 1/4 and 3/4 of the parent width.

Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Well the reason they are split like that is your `android:layout_weight`. If you want your prompts to have those weights assign those weights to your prompts.

Comment: Well... And any idea about how doing this ??....

Comment: So you want the views that come down to be 1/4 and 3/4?

Comment: what i want is that the prompts should be 1/4 and 3/4, but the expended items should be contained on 100% of the Parent layout width.

Comment: So is that image in your question your desired idea or is that what you want to fix? Im a little confused by this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47338/discussion-between-bigt-and-mehdi)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `android:layout_weight` attribute, you should be setting the `android:layout_width` attributes to `0dp`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adm_ll_media"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
>

    <ExpandableListView 
        android:id="@+id/adm_list_media"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <ExpandableListView 
        android:id="@+id/adm_add_media"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. But event using the `Odp` for the width, the behavior of `layout_weight` remains the same, and it's applied to expended elements not only prompts.

Comment: Could you provide us with two screenshots; current, and expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If by prompt you mean the Label (v list1) and by expanded element you mean your list, then I believe you should try adding a separate TextView over both of your lists which will work like your Prompt. Assign them the weights (for the 1/4 and 3/4 ratio) and then a width of wrap content to your lists.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adm_ll_media"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="v list1">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="v list2">
    </LinearLayout>          


     Your ListViews here with a layout_width of match_parent, within an another LinearLayout with layout_width = match_parent
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Edited as per your new image. Please try and lemme know if this works. Also if there's only 1 label (header as v list1) you are having inside the list then you simply use ListView now since the headers are achieved using TextViews.